# Custom tables (SPSS) in R?

Tags: r

Almost a year ago I made the switch from SPSS to R. Really like it! The only thing I'm missing is something like the custom tables-function in SPSS. Most of the time I use the janitor-package for my tables, but I'm missing two types of tables. Is there a package or function I could be using?

My df would look something like this:

[image]

In added icture I made two basic examples of the type of tables I want to make. It has 3 variables:  Gender, Age and a misc third one. All the values are counts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the first, you can use `ftable()`:

```
with(dat, ftable(gender, age, misc3))

           misc3 FALSE TRUE
gender age                 
female <18           5    8
       18+           5    7
male   <18           5    8
       18+           6    6
```

For the second, you can bind two tables:

```
with(dat, cbind(table(misc3, age), table(misc3, gender)))

      <18 18+ female male
FALSE  10  11     10   11
TRUE   16  13     15   14
```

Data:

```
set.seed(33)
dat <- data.frame(gender = sample(c("male", "female"), 50, replace = TRUE),
                  age = sample(c("<18", "18+"), 50, replace = TRUE),
                  misc3 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50, replace = TRUE))
```